# BULK IMPORT corrupts data

Tags: sql-server

I'm using BULK IMPORT to load tab-delimited UTF-8 data into a table.

A field containing the value `Île-de-France` gets loaded

into an `NVARCHAR()` or `VARCHAR()` column as `├Äle-de-France`

How can I ensure that this corruption doesn't happen, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server doesn't support UTF-8 for bulk insert (I think the 2016 version does). You'll have to convert your file to UTF-16, then you'll be able to load it correctly.

Comment: @radders Are you sure the correct version of BCP is called? See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverfaq/2009/06/03/bcp-command-using-code-page-65001-fails-if-both-sql-server-2000-and-sql-server-2005-tools-are-installed/.

Comment: Also, it appears there are more users who are still getting conflicts with UTF-8, see https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/370419/bulk-insert-and-bcp-does-not-recognize-codepage-65001. Switching to UTF-16 should solve it anyway (if it's possible, of course)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to those who answered - pointed me in the right direction.

I created a C# program to read the UTF-8 file and save it as UTF-16 and all is well...